# Area of a region in a plane

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Find the area of the region 
$$R =[ (x, y) \ | -3\leq x \leq 1 − y^2]$$

Working: 
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-3}^{l-y^2}dx dy$$
But i seem to get the wrong answer. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please show us your work and then we would love to help you find where you made a mistake!

Comment: The limits on $y$ are iffy. For what values of $y$ is $-3 = 1- y^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

From $x=1-y^2$ we have $y =\pm \sqrt{1-x}$ and the area is simply:
$$
A= 2\int_{-3}^1 \sqrt{1-x} dx
$$